# How to disable CXF webservice listing page?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I am using cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws with Spring Boot for SOAP Services.
The web application has the URL http://localhost:8080/abc/def/.
The WSDL must be located at http://localhost:8080/abc/def/service?wsdl.

application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/abc/def
cxf.path=/
```

Endpoint registration in Application.java:

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint(MySoapService service) {
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(service);
    endpoint.publish("/service");
    return endpoint;
}
```

As a result, the WSDL is placed correctly at http://localhost:8080/abc/def/service?wsdl.
But at http://localhost:8080/abc/def, instead of the web application, there is a cxf page with a list of services.
How can I disable it and make the web app open?

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the service list page generated by cxf you can add the following line in your `application.properties` file:

```
cxf.servlet.init.hide-service-list-page=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in web.xml you would have something like this:

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
               org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

This will disable the listing (show an empty page).

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
               org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <!-- security (listing has XSS) -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hide-service-list-page</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param> 
    </servlet>
```

Note that the listing has an XSS vulnerability in some versions of CXF (maybe not strictly XSS, but loads external CSS).